# Eval Command | Error doesn't send to the channel but in the terminal | discord.js

Tags: discord.js

My code:

```
if (command === 'eval') {
    let toEval = args.join(' ');
    let evaluated = inspect(eval(toEval, {depth: 0} ));
    try {
        if (toEval) {
            message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: 3066993,
                    title: 'Evaluation Executed!',
                    description: `${evaluated}`,
                    author: {
                        name: message.author.username,
                        icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
                    },
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                }
            });
        }
    } catch(error) {
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 15158332,
                title: 'Evaluation Cancelled',
                description: `${error}`,
                author: {
                    name: message.author.username,
                    icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
                },
                timestamp: new Date()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? If I typed in "!eval test" it sends the error in the terminal except in the channel. All I know the error is at Line 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the `eval()` function **into** your `try {} catch {}`. Just edit your code to something like that:

```js
if(command === "eval") {
  let toEval = args.join(" ");
  try {
    if(toEval) {
        let evaluated = inspect(eval(toEval, {depth: 0} ))
        message.channel.send({embed: {
        color: 3066993,
        title: "Evaluation Executed!",
        description: `${evaluated}`,
        author: {
          name: message.author.username,
          icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
        },
        timestamp: new Date(),
      }});
    }
} catch(error) {
      message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 15158332,
      title: "Evaluation Cancelled",
      description: `${error}`,
      author: {
        name: message.author.username,
        icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
      },
      timestamp: new Date()
    }});
  }
}
```

The error will be catched and sent in the channel!